# how can I limit the length of characters to be shown in the table td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

> I want to hide the extra characters in a table td if its lengths is
> more than 50 characters unless I click on that particular td to appear
> all the data

. [image]

> ex: the above table description td has a long data in it. and I only
> want the first 50 characters should be shown. this should be applied
> for the the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css property called `text-overflow` . Use this property in td style, don't forget to use `overflow` `white-space` properties as well. Make sure to define `max-width` property to td style.

```
<td
  style=
"max-width:100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis">


Table Data


</td>
```